# Does this VCO produce a sine wave or square wave

Tags: radar, vco

[image]I'm looking at the datasheet for the analog devices hmc431lp4 voltage controlled oscillator, and I can't tell if its output waveform is a sine wave or square wave. The datasheet doesn't label the oscillator as being harmonic or relaxation. I'm wondering because I am trying to understand a homemade radar system I found online. Do FMCW systems like this project require a sinusoidal RF signal to operate?

Link to [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc431.pdf).

Link to [project](http://hforsten.com/homemade-synthetic-aperture-radar.html) I'm looking at.

Comment: Just added a screenshot from the front page of the datasheet

Comment: I don't know the answer but the harmonics figures should give a clue. I notice that it is rated at > 500 W which, I suspect, should be mW.

Comment: So because the datasheet includes information on output harmonics the oscillator most likely produces a sinewave?

Comment: I would think so. A squarewave wouldn't have any even harmonics, only odd.

Comment: @Saunders an ideal square wave would have no 2nd harmonic and around -5dB third harmonic. The fact that the third harmonic is below the 2nd, and 30dB below the fundamental, indicates that they're not going for anything remotely square-ish. Everything else, put together, implies "pretty much sine".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This VCO outputs a frequency between 5.5 and 6.1 **GHz**.

It is sort of "implied" that the output signal will be a **sinewave** because:

- a "decent" square wave at that frequency would need a signal bandwidth of **several hundreds of GHz**. That's because a square wave relies on harmonic frequencies (multiples of the base frequency) to become "square". Read up on [Fourier analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis) to understand this
- this chip is designed to be used in RF transceivers, usually as a **local oscillator** for mixing up/down RF signals. This works best using sinewaves as RF designers want **one frequency** to deal with, not one frequency and all its harmonics (like a square wave would have).

Answer (score 3):

Neither. **The second and third harmonics are specified in the part of the datasheet page which you cut off**. Writing it like this clearly indicates that the harmonics are considered to be spurious to a sine wave. So even if you would actually design a circuit layout which let's say is able to transport up to e.g. 20GHz BW, you would not see a "rectangle", since the second harmonic is already significantly suppressed.